# Authenticating and sending a request with Java.net 's Http functionality

Tags: java, http

I want to use http requests to download some CSV's from a website. I want to do this with the java.net http packages.

I can access a webpage that has the correct download link(although the url itself doesn't start the download) by putting the appropriate RecordNumber from local storage to the URL

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
            .uri(URI.create("https://Website.com/record/index.asp?RecordNumber=72171371"))
            .build();

    HttpClient client = HttpClient.newBuilder()
            .version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_1_1)
            .followRedirects(HttpClient.Redirect.NORMAL)
            .connectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(20))
            .build();

    HttpResponse<String> response = HttpClient.newBuilder()
            .authenticator(new Authenticator() {
                @Override
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication("Username","Password".toCharArray());
                }
            }).build()
            .send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
    System.out.println(response.statusCode());
    System.out.println(response.body());
}
```

I currently get this response from my code:

```
302 <head><title>Object moved</title></head> <body><h1>Object Moved</h1>This object may be found <a HREF="/signin.asp">here</a>.</body>
```

My question is: How can I properly authenticate so that I am not redirected into sign in?

Bonus q: How would you attempt to download these files ? Will what I am doing even work given that there is no API for this website?

EDIT: Adding the websites code for the page. Here is the relevant server code...Going to attempt VGR's fantastic suggestion now as it seems to be handled with cookies:

```
   <table height="100%" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" >
    <tr>
        <td width="100%" height="100%" >
            <form name="loginform" id="loginForm" method="POST" action="signin.asp" style="margin: 0px" onsubmit="return signInFn.loginFormOnSubmit();">
                <input name="sdettifevalidyzrsxcmc" value="DT: 8/12/2020 5:15:25 PM" type="hidden">
                <input name="Page_Loaded" value="DT: 8/12/2020 5:24:30 PM" type="hidden">
                <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="mls-login">

                    <tr>
                        <td ><img src="images/Logo.jpg" width="240" height="60" /> </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="text-left pl-4"><span class="h4">Sign In to</span>
                            <img src="images/nergy-logo.jpg" width="90" height="30" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>

                        <td class="pl-2">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" style="width: 220px;" name="user_name" maxlength="8"
                                value="" placeholder="Enter Your ID"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="pl-2" >
                            <input class="form-control" type="password" style="width: 220px" name="pass" maxlength="20"
                                 placeholder="Password">
                        </td>
```

Comment: your link doesnt work

Comment: @J Asgarov, Edited it so that the "link" appeared correctly. It is actually an HTML response to my HTTP request. The "link" is the server/website redirecting me to the login page. Given that I am entering the URL of a page that is not the login page, It makes me think I haven't authenticated correctly.

Comment: Your options depend on the capabilities of the website you need to access. You should investigate if the website supports programmatic authorization i.e. via authorization header. Otherwise it will be hard to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

If the site has a sign-in page, it probably doesn’t use [HTTP authentication](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617).  Most likely, submitting the sign-in page’s form causes the server to send back one or more cookies representing a session.

You can try inspecting the `id` attributes of the form’s fields, as well as the `action` of the form itself, if it is in fact a standard HTML form.  But, realistically, not every form is that simple;  many have submit buttons that trigger JavaScript of varying degrees of complexity which ultimately send the information to the server in order to start a session.  Reverse engineering such a page can take days or weeks.

If you’re lucky enough that it’s a simple form, you can try to simulate a login, by [adding a CookieHandler](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpClient.Builder.html#cookieHandler(java.net.CookieHandler)) to an HttpClient and using that client to log into the site directly.

If the sign-in page is something like:

```
<form action="complete-login.asp">
    <label>Name: <input id="name"></label>
    <label>Password: <input id="password" type="password"></label>
</form>
```

Then you can submit a login directly:

```
CookieHandler cookieHandler = new CookieManager();

String signInFormBody =
    "name=" + URLEncoder.encode(username, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
    + "&"
    + "password=" + URLEncoder.encode(password, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

HttpClient client =
    HttpClient.newBuilder().cookieHandler(cookieHandler).build();

URI action = URI.create("http://Website.com/complete-login.asp");
HttpRequest loginRequest =
    HttpRequest.newBuilder(action)
        .post(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(signInFormBody))
        .build();

HttpResponse<?> loginResponse = client.send(loginRequest,
    HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.discarding());

int statuscode = loginResponse.statusCode();
if (statusCode >= 400) {
    throw new IOException("Login failed with status code " + statusCode);
}
```

Now the `cookieHandler` should have the login session in it, so you can reuse it for future requests:

```
HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
        .uri(URI.create("https://Website.com/record/index.asp?RecordNumber=72171371"))
        .build();

// Notice the reuse of cookieHandler...
client = HttpClient.newBuilder()
        .cookieHandler(cookieHandler)
        .version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_1_1)
        .followRedirects(HttpClient.Redirect.NORMAL)
        .connectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(20))
        .build();

HttpResponse<String> response = 
        client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());

statuscode = response.statusCode();
if (statusCode >= 400) {
    throw new IOException("Download failed with status code " + statusCode);
}
```

As for downloading, since you have an `HttpResponse<String>`, you already have the body as a String:

```
String downloadedContent = response.body();
```

If there’s a chance that the download will be large, you probably don’t want it all in memory.  You can send the download right to a file:

```
Path downloadedFile = Files.createTempFile(null, ".dat");
HttpResponse<?> response = 
    client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofFile(downloadedFile));
```

Or you can do whatever you want with the download by requesting it as an InputStream:

```
HttpResponse<InputStream> response = 
        client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofInputStream());

try (InputStream downloadStream = response.body()) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the previous response.      I am currently getting a loginResponse status code of 200, and a loginResponse body that is null. Any idea why it might null?

Comment: Probably due to the use of `HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.discarding()`.  You can replace it with a different handler if you want the details of that response.  I was under the impression that only the cookies were important, and those should already be in the CookieHandler when the response is received.

Comment: I seem to be getting the same responsebody for each. Not sure why the cookies aren't working, as It does look like this:

Comment: I seem to be getting the same responsebody for each. Not sure why the cookies aren't working, as It does look like this:                                                                
  <form action="complete-login.asp">
    <label>Name: <input id="name"></label>
    <label>Password: <input id="password" type="password"></label>
</form>                                                                                                                                    I expect I need to interact with the Javascript on the page to login. I will try using HTMLUnit.